# How to allow www-data to execute ping?

Tags: php, linux, apache

I try to execute a ping command with the user www-data

```
$command    = 'ping -c 4 www.stackoverflow.com 2>&1';
$result     = shell_exec($command);
```

But i always get `ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted`.
So i tried to allow the command by executing `visudo` and adding this line:

`www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/ping`

Then i restarted apache2 and tried it again, but i still get `Operation not permitted`.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Can you use `ping` with the `www-data` outside of php script? Try `sudo -u www-data ping -c 4 www.stackoverflow.com`

Comment: No, i already tried this, i still get `operation not permitted`.

Comment: Did you see this [Ubuntu Forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=927709)? Try `sudo chmod u+s `which ping``

Comment: @Lukas Hajdu, i had to change it to `sudo chmod u+s /bin/ping` now it is working, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The use of setuid, that provoques that `ping` is executed with the user of the ping itself (root) and not the user who launches the command (here www-data), is an old way to solve this problem, and not the best one today.

See [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/915346). Recent linux distribution use kernel capabilities to solve that. Run `getcap /bin/ping`, it should return: `/bin/ping = cap_net_raw+ep`.

If not, you can manually set the capabilities. Run, as root:

```
# setcap cap_net_raw+ep /bin/ping
```

Or, more elegant, re-installe the appropriate package. In Debian distributions and derivatives, this is `iputils-ping`.